# the mouseout event occur more than one time

Tags: javascript, mouseout

Hi:
when I add a mouseout event to a parent element,it seems that all of its child are added this event also,it works well if the event is a mouse click and etc.

However for the mouseout event,this will cause some unexpected result.

Take a look at this example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init(){
                document.getElementById('par').onmouseout=function(){alert('mouse out')};
            }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='init()'>
        <div id="par" style="width:400px;height:300px">
            <div style="background-color:red;width:100%;height:150px"></div>
            <div style="background-color:black;width:100%;height:150px"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

please Move from the red div to the black div,then move out of the black div,then you will get two alert window,I just want one.

So how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible using plain javascript without the [mouseleave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536946%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) event, which, to my knowledge, is only supported by Internet Explorer.

Javascript toolkits may provide a solution, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for instance [emulates](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) that event:

> The `mouseleave` event differs from
>   `mouseout` in the way it handles event
>   bubbling. If `mouseout` were used in
>   this example, then when the mouse
>   pointer moved out of the **Inner**
>   element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable
>   behavior. The `mouseleave` event, on
>   the other hand, only triggers its
>   handler when the mouse leaves the
>   element it is bound to, not a
>   descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse
>   leaves the **Outer** element, but not the
>   **Inner** element.